# unitTest a python 3 metaclass

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, python-import, metaclass

I have a metaclass that set a class property `my_new_property` when it loads the class. This file will me named `my_meta` and the code is this

```
def remote_function():
  # Get some data from a request to other site
  return 'remote_response'

class MyMeta(type):
  def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
    print("It is in")
    obj = super().__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
    new_value = remote_function()
    setattr(obj, 'my_new_property', new_value)
    return obj
```

The functionality to set the property works fine, however when writing the test file `tests.py` with **only one code line**:

```
from my_meta import MyMeta
```

The meta code is executed. As a consequence, it executes the real method `remote_function`.

The question is... as the meta code is executed only by using the `import` from the test file, how could I mock the method `remote_function`?

Comment: Importing a file does not magically call a function that's defined in that file. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Almost certainly, you are also importing something that defines a class using MyMeta as the metaclass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Importing the file as you show us won't trigger execution of the metaclass code.

However, importing *any* file (includng the one where the metaclass is), where there is a class that makes use of this metaclass, will run the code in the metaclass `__new__`  method - as parsing a class body defined with the `class` statement does just that: call the metaclass to create a new class instance.

So, the recomendation is: do not have your metaclass `__new__` or `__init__` methods to trigger side effects, like accessing remote stuff, if that can't be done in a seamless and innocuous way. Not only testing, but importing modules of your app in a Python shell will also trigger the behavior.

You could have a method in the  metaclass to inialize with the remote value, and when you are about to actually use those, you'd explicitly call a such "remote_init" - like in

```
class MyMeta(type):
  def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
    print("It is in")
    obj = super().__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
    new_value = remote_function()
    setattr(obj, 'my_new_property', new_value)
    return obj

  def remote_init(cls):
      if hasattr(cls, "my_new_property"): 
           return
      cls.my_new_property = remote_function()
```

The remote_init method, being placed in the metaclass will behave jsut like a class method for the instantiated classes, but won't be visible (for dir or attribute retrieval), from the class instances.
This is the safest thing to do.

If you want to avoid the explicit step, which is understanble, you could use a setting in a configuration file, and a test inside the remote_function on whether to trigger the actual networking code, or just return a local, dummy value. You then make the configurations differ for testing/staging/production.

And, finally, you could just separate `remote_method` in another module, import that first, patch it out with `unitttest.mock.patch`, and the import the metaclass containing module - when it runs and calls the method, it will be just the pacthed version. This will work for your tests, but won't fix the problem of you triggering side-effects in other occasions (like in other tests that load this module).

Of course, for that to work you have to import the module containing the metaclass and  any classes defined with it inside your test function, in a region where `mock.patch` is active, not importing it at the top of the file.  There is just no problem in importing things inside test methods to have control over the importing process itself.